# Qt after typedef no autocompletion

Tags: ide, qt4

I am trying some codes from ITK in Qt4 now, just as a IDE.
One interesting thing is after typedef the object cannot auto complete the possible properties.

```
// Declare the image
typedef itk::Image<short, 3> ImageType;

ImageType::SizeType imSize = {{256, 256, 10}};
ImageType::Pointer im = ImageType::New();
im->SetRegions(imSize);
im->Allocate();
```

Here im-> has the trouble. Everytime I have to fill by hand.

I guess this is not a bug?

Comment: Qt Creator, under windows 7 when it goes to VS2010, no problem

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. It doesn't have anything to do with ITK:

#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
  void TestFunction(){}
};

int main (int , char *[])
{
  MyClass myClass;
  myClass.TestFunction();
  
  MyClass* myClass2 = new MyClass;
  myClass2->TestFunction();

  typedef MyClass MyClassType;
  MyClassType myClass3;
  myClass3.

  return 0;
}

Here, myClass3. does not produce the autocomplete list, while myClass and myClass2 DO produce the autocomplete list.

Comment: Hope someday it can be fixed...